# Response Payload incorrect using Youtube Data API

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to use Youtube's Data API to get some info on various channels, but when I run my build:

```
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3',developerKey=api_key)


request = youtube.channels().list(
    part = "statistics",
    forUsername = "tonetalks"
)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

It returns this:

```
{'kind': 'youtube#channelListResponse', 'etag': 'RuuXzTIr0OoDqI4S0RU6n4FqKEM', 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 0, 'resultsPerPage': 5}}
```

Any thoughts how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forUsername` is incorrect. If you're looking for [this "tonetalks" channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfP8rCe_fAITriqI3UPYF0Q), you'll have to use its id `UCfP8rCe_fAITriqI3UPYF0Q` (from the above channel URL):

```
request = youtube.channels().list(
    part = "statistics",
    id = "UCfP8rCe_fAITriqI3UPYF0Q",
)
```

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "5gs56_i4Xd_fQ4A1OkQEnWWnX7A",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "m7gogJwH4TshrBX4PCiuFP5MsJI",
      "id": "UCfP8rCe_fAITriqI3UPYF0Q",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "6033544",
        "subscriberCount": "81200",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "229"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```